# Regex in Notepad++ for replacement

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

i've search for that info, but can't to figure out how to understand properly a regular expression.
I have a html file and there are multiple `<img>` tags. Each of these tags have attribe `src` with following data: `/newsletter/images/light/b/NUMERICVALUE/IMAGENAME.jpg`

Assuming that the `NUMERICVALUE` and the `IMAGENAME` are always different value in each `src` attribute.

What i need is to remove `/NUMERICVALUE` from each url. How i suppose to do that ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Here are a list of examples:

> `/newsletter/images/light/b/617359405/lf-header.jpg`
>   `/newsletter/images/light/b/617359406/up-logo.jpg`
>   `/newsletter/images/light/b/617359407/logo-header.jpg`

Comment: If its a list and they are all the same length, alt+leftmouse for column select, delete

Comment: @Alex K. no, there are placed inside the whole html document. so no way to use alt+leftmouse combination here. There are 2000+ lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search: `src=\"\/newsletter\/images\/light\/b\/[^\/]*\/([^\"]*)\"`
Replace: `src="/newsletter/images/light/b/\1"`

Explanation:

- Defines the full URI: `\/newsletter\/images\/light\/b\/[^\/]*\/([^\"]*)`
- This will find anything WITHOUT a / slash `[^\/]*`
- This will find anything WITHOUT a " quote `([^\"]*)`
- The `(` and `)` tells the regular expression engine to capture the content of it
- In the replacement `\1` forces the regular expression engine to insert capture `1` at this place

**Edit**: Updated to be used on all `src=` attributes as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: can we do it with all `src` and not just with only `<img src=''` ? thanks for explaination, it will takes me a hours to understand it :)

Comment: @aspirinemaga I've edited my answer to match on all `src=""` attributes.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I've searched for `\/newsletter\/images\/light\/b\/[^\/]*\/` and replaced it with `/newsletter/images/light/b/\1`

Answer (score 1):

I guess NUMERICVALUE is an actual numeric value, so a simple solution:

```
Find what: /newsletter/images/light/b/\d+/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).jpg
Replace with: /newsletter/images/light/b/\1.jpg
```

change contents of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to what you need.

Comment: Exactly, this is what i've search for. Thanks a lot jornb87!

Answer (score 0):

This barely programming-related but anyway:

```
Find what: (<img src=.*/)\d+/
Replace with: \1
```

Input:

```
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/654/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/5752/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/78697345/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/7896789/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/45/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/8/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/4567837/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
```

Output:

```
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
<img src="/newsletter/images/light/b/IMAGENAME.jpg"/>
```

Comment: thanks for post, but NUMERICVALUE is always different in each path. I've added an example list.

Comment: Updated my answer as well. Next time please try to give such details earlier ;)

Comment: Also might I recommend writing a script that actually does this replacement (using Perl for example) so you don't have to open the file in Notepad++ to do such manipulations. It's faster :)

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure you have selected "Regular expression" at the bottom of the Replace form and you have latest Notepad++ (mine is v5.9.8). There were improvements for more powerful regexes on latest updates.

Comment: Just to let you know - your regular expression will catch wrong results on something like this: `<img src="some/path/file.ext" rel="/1234/"` (Captured will be `<img src="some/path/file.ext" rel="/1234/`).


Source of this missleading is your path expression `.*/\d+/`, which will catch everything until `/<number>/`. This of course includes quotes and everythign else.


Even `<img src="some/path/file.ext" /><a href="REST/full/1/">See 1</a>` this will fail (Captured will be `<img src="some/path/file.ext" /><a href="REST/full/1/`).